# When adjoining a new sort that is supposed to model the powerset of the original domain of discourse, what is the appropriate notion of embedding?

Tags: logic

**Edit.** This question hasn't generated much interest so far. Any suggestions for improvement would be much appreciated, so please leave a comment. Best wishes.

---

Often, we begin with a first-order theory $(T,L)$ and then adjoin a 'sort of all subsets' to obtain a bigger theory $(T',L').$ My concern is this. I want to know that if we're working in the bigger theory $(T',L')$ and we prove a theorem in the language of $L$, then this theorem can be deduced from $T$ alone.

Lets consider the issue in more detail.

By the term *first-order theory*, let us mean an ordered pair $(T,L)$ where $L$ is a (many-sorted) first-order language, and $T$ is an arbitrary (not necessarily deductively closed) subset of $L$.

Now consider a first-order theory $(T,L)$ with a single sort $X$. We can obtain a new first-order theory $(T',L')$ by adding

- a new sort $\mathcal{P}(X)$
- a membership relation $\in\; : X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X),$
- an axiom of extensionality for the elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$
- and a comprehension* schema.

Now presumably, the inclusion map $f : L \rightarrow L'$ is some sort of an embedding (not just of the languages, but more importantly, of the theories). What is the appropriate notion of embedding for this situation, and how do we know that $f$ has the property of interest? By proving that $f$ is indeed an embedding in the appropriate sense, we should be able to deduce as an immediate corollary that if we're working in the bigger theory $(T',L')$ and we prove a theorem in the language of $L$, then this theorem can be deduced from $T$ alone.

*The comprehension schema can be stated as follows. For all natural numbers $n$ and $m$ and all formulae $$\varphi(a_0,\cdots,a_n,A_0,\cdots,A_m,y)$$ in the language $L'$, we take the following as an axiom.

> For all $(a_0 : X)(\cdots)(a_n : X)$ and all $(A_0 :
>  \mathcal{P}(X))(\cdots)(A_m : \mathcal{P}(X))$, there exists $Y :
>  \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that for all $x : X$ we have $$x \in Y
>  \Leftrightarrow \varphi(a_0,\cdots,a_n,A_0,\cdots,A_m,y).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you are looking for is [conservative extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension).

I think the easiest way to show that $T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$ is to note that every model $\mathcal{M}$ of $T$ can be extended to a model $\mathcal{M}'$ of $T'$ in the obvious way (by setting $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to be the usual powerset). In the wikipedia article I linked to, this is called a model theoretic conservative extension. It follows that $T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$ using the completeness theorem for first order logic.

Something to note about this construction is that it is not always as useful as you might think. For example, you might expect that if $T$ is Peano arithmetic $\mathbf{PA}$, then $T'$ is [second order arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) $\mathbf{Z}_2$. This is *not* the case, and in fact $\mathbf{Z}_2$ is definitely *not* conservative over $\mathbf{PA}$.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It's still not clear to me what sort of an embedding $f$ is; in all other respects, your answer is wonderful.

Comment: Maybe [interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability) is the definition you want?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure... the linked article isn't exactly explicit about what constitutes an interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a special name for the embedding; in this case $L$ is just a subset of $L'$ so there's not even much need to talk about "embedding".  There is one piece of terminology; we say that $T'$ is conservative over $T$ if, for every sentence $\phi \in L$, if $\phi$ is provable in $T'$ then it is provable in $T$.

In most cases of interest, the second-order theory with full comprehension will not be conservative over the original theory. Usually we have to weaken the comprehension scheme to fix this. For example, the second-order theory conservative over PA is known as $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, and is obtained by extending the language and then adding comprehension and induction axioms for all arithmetical formulas (formulas that do not quantify over sets).

Somewhat similarly, NBG set theory is a second-order extension of ZFC set theory, and NBG is conservative over ZFC for sentences in the language of ZFC. But NBG does not have full comprhension, it only has comprehension for formulas that do not quantify over classes. If we add full comprehension we obtain something like Morse-Kelly set theory which is no longer conservative over ZFC.

In general, the choice of the right comprehension scheme to get conservativity is delicate. If you add *no* additional axioms than the second-order extension is conservative over the original, but not useful for proving any new theorems. If you add too many comprehension axioms, the new theory is likely to be too strong. So some amount of context-specific proof is required for each result to show that a particular amount of comprehension is still conservative over the original theory.

Comment: Carl thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused about this comment: "in most cases of interest, the second-order theory with full comprehension will not be conservative over the original theory." I don't get this. I mean, obviously if we're dealing with a theory of arithmetic and we not only adjoin a new sort $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ together with a comprehension schema, but also strength our induction axiom as well, the result needn't be a conservative extension. But, what if we don't strengthen our induction axiom?

Comment: Here's some motivation for the original question, which may clarify my concerns and motivation. Suppose we're working in the first-order theory of partially ordered sets. We get as far as we can within the theory, and then decide that we need to be talking about down-sets, principal down sets etc. So, we want to move to a bigger language that has a sort representing the powerset of the original domain of discourse. My concern is, do we lose generality by doing this?

Comment: Ah I see. You write: "If you add no additional axioms than the second-order extension is conservative over the original." This clears my confusion.

Comment: In the context of arithmetic, one would want to add both comprehension and induction (at least the single axiom "$[0 \in X \land (\forall n)(n \in X \to n+1\in X)] \to (\forall n)(n \in X)$." But in the ZFC/NBG example there is no extra induction. Re the last comment, if you add no new axioms at all you get a conservative extension but you can't even prove any sets exist!

Comment: The normal way people work with things like down sets is not to extend the theory of partial orders, it's just to study partial orders in ZFC. Then they don't have to worry about exactly what comprehension axioms to use, because they already know ZFC.

Comment: In NBG the extra axioms are (strengthened) foundation and limitation of size.

Comment: @CarlMummert, please tell me what you think of the following argument. Argument: going straight to ZFC is a bad way to study down-sets, because if you prove something about down-sets using ZFC, you can't instantly import that into a different foundation, like NFU. So, we're better off proving things under minimal hypotheses. If a theorem about down-sets can be expressed and comfortably proved just by adjoining a single new sort for the powerset of the original domain of discourse, together with a comprehension schema, then this is a better way of going about it.